# Intern sends headers data into address bar

Tags: intern

Every time I run ./node_modules/.bin/intern-runner config=tests/intern
internjs sends some junk data into browser address bar and tries to execute it.

```
Executing: [get: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22a%22%20style%3D%22left%3A%200%3B%20position%3A%20absolute%3B%20top%3A%20-1000px%3B%22%3Ea%3C%2Fdiv%3E])
```

???

And then it finally get the valid url where it can continue with testing Suite.

```
10:36:14.837 INFO - Executing: [get: http://localhost:9000/index.html])
```

I've tested it on firefox 27, 32, 38.2 , on Linux box and windows 7 + cygwin. 
Everywhere I found the same behaviour. It doesn't appear to be a problem with selenium (tried grid config, standalone ) or the driver itself. 
My config is mostly from https://github.com/theintern/intern-tutorial

This behaviour causes problems with IE (11 in my case) as it's not able to get pass the first junk request and gets stuck at it.

```
10:35:04.654 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
10:35:04.815 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 24.85-b03
10:35:04.815 INFO - OS: Linux 3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64 amd64
10:35:04.854 INFO - v2.47.1, with Core v2.47.1. Built from revision 411b314
10:35:05.207 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
10:35:05.208 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
10:35:05.208 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
10:35:05.208 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
10:35:05.660 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
10:35:05.660 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
10:36:08.181 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{idle-timeout=60, platform=LINUX, browserName=firefox, browserstack.selenium_version=2.45.0, name=tests/intern, version=38.2}]])
10:36:08.190 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{idle-timeout=60, platform=LINUX, browserName=firefox, browserstack.selenium_version=2.45.0, name=tests/intern, version=38.2}]
10:36:13.368 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{idle-timeout=60, platform=LINUX, browserName=firefox, browserstack.selenium_version=2.45.0, name=tests/intern, version=38.2}]]
10:36:13.378 INFO - Executing: [get: about:blank])
10:36:13.412 INFO - Done: [get: about:blank]
10:36:13.420 INFO - Executing: [get local storage size])
10:36:13.422 INFO - Executing: [get location context])
10:36:13.425 INFO - Executing: [get application cache status])
10:36:13.427 INFO - Executing: [take screenshot])
10:36:13.428 INFO - Executing: [execute async script: arguments[0](true);, []])
10:36:13.435 WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: driver (org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver) does not support org.openqa.selenium.html5.LocationContext
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'xxxxx', ip: '-------', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_85'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.html5.Utils.convert(Utils.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.html5.Utils.getLocationContext(Utils.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.html5.GetLocationContext.call(GetLocationContext.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.html5.GetLocationContext.call(GetLocationContext.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
10:36:13.440 WARN - Exception: driver (org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver) does not support org.openqa.selenium.html5.LocationContext
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: '-------', ip: '-------', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_85'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
10:36:13.438 WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: driver (org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver) does not support org.openqa.selenium.html5.WebStorage
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: '-------', ip: '-------', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_85'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.html5.Utils.convert(Utils.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.html5.Utils.getWebStorage(Utils.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.html5.GetLocalStorageSize.call(GetLocalStorageSize.java:31)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.html5.GetLocalStorageSize.call(GetLocalStorageSize.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
10:36:13.467 WARN - Exception: driver (org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver) does not support org.openqa.selenium.html5.WebStorage
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: '-------', ip: '-------', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_85'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
10:36:13.437 WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: driver (org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver) does not support org.openqa.selenium.html5.ApplicationCache
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: '-------', ip: '-------', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_85'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.html5.Utils.convert(Utils.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.html5.Utils.getApplicationCache(Utils.java:47)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.html5.GetAppCacheStatus.call(GetAppCacheStatus.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.html5.GetAppCacheStatus.call(GetAppCacheStatus.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
10:36:13.487 WARN - Exception: driver (org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver) does not support org.openqa.selenium.html5.ApplicationCache
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: '-------', ip: '-------', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_85'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
10:36:13.503 INFO - Executing: [get window size])
10:36:13.504 INFO - Executing: [doubleclick: no args])
10:36:13.505 INFO - Executing: [Long press: null])
10:36:13.513 INFO - Done: [take screenshot]
10:36:13.539 INFO - Done: [execute async script: arguments[0](true);, []]
10:36:13.557 INFO - Done: [get window size]
10:36:13.563 INFO - Executing: [set window size])
10:36:13.572 WARN - Exception thrown
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Underlying driver does not implement advanced user interactions yet.
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.getTouch(EventFiringWebDriver.java:312)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.interactions.touch.LongPressOnElement.call(LongPressOnElement.java:41)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.interactions.touch.LongPressOnElement.call(LongPressOnElement.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
10:36:13.574 WARN - Exception: Underlying driver does not implement advanced user interactions yet.
10:36:13.574 WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: [JavaScript Error: "Argument to isShown must be of type Element" {file: "file:///tmp/anonymous6679311816744638276webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/synthetic-mouse.js" line: 8547}]'[JavaScript Error: "Argument to isShown must be of type Element" {file: "file:///tmp/anonymous6679311816744638276webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/synthetic-mouse.js" line: 8547}]' when calling method: [wdIMouse::doubleClick]
Command duration or timeout: 12 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: '-------', ip: '-------', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_85'
Session ID: 6ba8c75c-021b-4a46-8368-6dd3c0487142
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=38.2.1}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:618)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteExecuteMethod.execute(RemoteExecuteMethod.java:33)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteMouse.doubleClick(RemoteMouse.java:71)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.internal.EventFiringMouse.doubleClick(EventFiringMouse.java:46)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.interactions.DoubleClickInSession.call(DoubleClickInSession.java:34)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.interactions.DoubleClickInSession.call(DoubleClickInSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: [JavaScript Error: "Argument to isShown must be of type Element" {file: "file:///tmp/anonymous6679311816744638276webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/synthetic-mouse.js" line: 8547}]'[JavaScript Error: "Argument to isShown must be of type Element" {file: "file:///tmp/anonymous6679311816744638276webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/synthetic-mouse.js" line: 8547}]' when calling method: [wdIMouse::doubleClick]
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: '-------', ip: '-------', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_85'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.mouseDoubleClick(file:///tmp/anonymous6679311816744638276webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:11092)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///tmp/anonymous6679311816744638276webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12643)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///tmp/anonymous6679311816744638276webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12648)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///tmp/anonymous6679311816744638276webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12590)
10:36:13.578 WARN - Exception: [JavaScript Error: "Argument to isShown must be of type Element" {file: "file:///tmp/anonymous6679311816744638276webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/synthetic-mouse.js" line: 8547}]'[JavaScript Error: "Argument to isShown must be of type Element" {file: "file:///tmp/anonymous6679311816744638276webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/synthetic-mouse.js" line: 8547}]' when calling method: [wdIMouse::doubleClick]
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'xxxxx', ip: 'xxxxxxxxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_85'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
10:36:13.597 INFO - Done: [set window size]
10:36:13.601 INFO - Executing: [get: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Ctitle%3Ea%3C%2Ftitle%3E])
10:36:13.650 INFO - Done: [get: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Ctitle%3Ea%3C%2Ftitle%3E]
10:36:13.655 INFO - Executing: [get title])
10:36:13.664 INFO - Done: [get title]
10:36:13.669 INFO - Executing: [get: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Cstyle%3E%23a%7Bwidth%3A8px%3Bheight%3A8px%3B-ms-transform%3Ascale(0.5)%3B-moz-transform%3Ascale(0.5)%3B-webkit-transform%3Ascale(0.5)%3Btransform%3Ascale(0.5)%3B%7D%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22a%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E])
10:36:13.691 INFO - Done: [get: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Cstyle%3E%23a%7Bwidth%3A8px%3Bheight%3A8px%3B-ms-transform%3Ascale(0.5)%3B-moz-transform%3Ascale(0.5)%3B-webkit-transform%3Ascale(0.5)%3Btransform%3Ascale(0.5)%3B%7D%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22a%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E]
10:36:13.699 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return (function () {
                        var bbox = document.getElementById('a').getBoundingClientRect();
                        return bbox.right - bbox.left === 4;
                    }).apply(this, arguments);, []])
10:36:13.707 INFO - Done: [execute script: return (function () {
                        var bbox = document.getElementById('a').getBoundingClientRect();
                        return bbox.right - bbox.left === 4;
                    }).apply(this, arguments);, []]
10:36:13.711 INFO - Executing: [get: about:blank])
10:36:13.734 INFO - Done: [get: about:blank]
10:36:13.742 INFO - Executing: [fetching available log types])
10:36:13.744 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.tagName: html])
10:36:13.746 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.tagName: html])
10:36:13.751 INFO - Done: [fetching available log types]
10:36:13.795 INFO - Done: [find element: By.tagName: html]
10:36:13.801 INFO - Executing: [tag name: 0 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (6ba8c75c-021b-4a46-8368-6dd3c0487142)] -> tag name: html]])
10:36:13.803 INFO - Done: [find element: By.tagName: html]
10:36:13.811 INFO - Done: [tag name: 0 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (6ba8c75c-021b-4a46-8368-6dd3c0487142)] -> tag name: html]]
10:36:13.812 INFO - Executing: [get element attribute: 0 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (6ba8c75c-021b-4a46-8368-6dd3c0487142)] -> tag name: html], nonexisting])
10:36:13.819 INFO - Done: [get element attribute: 0 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (6ba8c75c-021b-4a46-8368-6dd3c0487142)] -> tag name: html], nonexisting]
10:36:13.823 INFO - Executing: [get: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22a%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E])
10:36:13.847 INFO - Done: [get: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22a%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E]
10:36:13.851 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return document.getElementById("a");, []])
10:36:13.859 INFO - Done: [execute script: return document.getElementById("a");, []]
10:36:13.862 INFO - Executing: [tag name: 1 [org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@294ad511 -> unknown locator]])
10:36:13.869 INFO - Done: [tag name: 1 [org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@294ad511 -> unknown locator]]
10:36:13.873 INFO - Executing: [get: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22a%22%20style%3D%22opacity%3A%20.1%3B%22%3Ea%3C%2Fdiv%3E])
10:36:13.898 INFO - Done: [get: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22a%22%20style%3D%22opacity%3A%20.1%3B%22%3Ea%3C%2Fdiv%3E]
10:36:13.902 INFO - Executing: [execute script: var o = document.getElementById("a").style.opacity; return o && o.charAt(0) === "0";, []])
10:36:13.910 INFO - Done: [execute script: var o = document.getElementById("a").style.opacity; return o && o.charAt(0) === "0";, []]
10:36:13.913 INFO - Executing: [execute script: document.getElementById("a").style.opacity = "0";, []])
10:36:13.919 INFO - Done: [execute script: document.getElementById("a").style.opacity = "0";, []]
10:36:13.923 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.id: a])
10:36:13.929 INFO - Done: [find element: By.id: a]
10:36:13.936 INFO - Executing: [is displayed: 2 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (6ba8c75c-021b-4a46-8368-6dd3c0487142)] -> id: a]])
10:36:13.943 INFO - Done: [is displayed: 2 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (6ba8c75c-021b-4a46-8368-6dd3c0487142)] -> id: a]]
10:36:13.949 INFO - Executing: [get: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22a%22%20style%3D%22left%3A%200%3B%20position%3A%20absolute%3B%20top%3A%20-1000px%3B%22%3Ea%3C%2Fdiv%3E])
10:36:13.970 INFO - Done: [get: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22a%22%20style%3D%22left%3A%200%3B%20position%3A%20absolute%3B%20top%3A%20-1000px%3B%22%3Ea%3C%2Fdiv%3E]
10:36:13.974 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.id: a])
10:36:13.980 INFO - Done: [find element: By.id: a]
10:36:13.984 INFO - Executing: [is displayed: 3 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (6ba8c75c-021b-4a46-8368-6dd3c0487142)] -> id: a]])
10:36:13.995 INFO - Done: [is displayed: 3 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (6ba8c75c-021b-4a46-8368-6dd3c0487142)] -> id: a]]
10:36:13.999 INFO - Executing: [get: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Cform%20method%3D%22get%22%20action%3D%22about%3Ablank%22%3E%3Cinput%20id%3D%22a%22%20type%3D%22submit%22%20name%3D%22a%22%20value%3D%22a%22%3E%3C%2Fform%3E])
10:36:14.023 INFO - Done: [get: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Cform%20method%3D%22get%22%20action%3D%22about%3Ablank%22%3E%3Cinput%20id%3D%22a%22%20type%3D%22submit%22%20name%3D%22a%22%20value%3D%22a%22%3E%3C%2Fform%3E]
10:36:14.031 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.id: a])
10:36:14.045 INFO - Done: [find element: By.id: a]
10:36:14.050 INFO - Executing: [submit: 4 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (6ba8c75c-021b-4a46-8368-6dd3c0487142)] -> id: a]])
10:36:14.069 INFO - Done: [submit: 4 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (6ba8c75c-021b-4a46-8368-6dd3c0487142)] -> id: a]]
10:36:14.072 INFO - Executing: [get current url])
10:36:14.079 INFO - Done: [get current url]
10:36:14.084 INFO - Executing: [get: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22a%22%20style%3D%22margin%3A%203000px%3B%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E])
10:36:14.105 INFO - Done: [get: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22a%22%20style%3D%22margin%3A%203000px%3B%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E]
10:36:14.109 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.id: a])
10:36:14.122 INFO - Done: [find element: By.id: a]
10:36:14.126 INFO - Executing: [get location: 5 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (6ba8c75c-021b-4a46-8368-6dd3c0487142)] -> id: a]])
10:36:14.135 INFO - Done: [get location: 5 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (6ba8c75c-021b-4a46-8368-6dd3c0487142)] -> id: a]]
10:36:14.140 INFO - Executing: [get: about:blank?1])
10:36:14.165 INFO - Done: [get: about:blank?1]
10:36:14.170 INFO - Executing: [refresh])
10:36:14.191 INFO - Done: [refresh]
10:36:14.200 INFO - Executing: [get: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Cscript%3Ecounter%20%3D%200%3B%20var%20d%20%3D%20document%3B%20d.onclick%20%3D%20d.onmousedown%20%3D%20d.onmouseup%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%20counter%2B%2B%3B%20%7D%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E])
10:36:14.220 INFO - Done: [get: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Cscript%3Ecounter%20%3D%200%3B%20var%20d%20%3D%20document%3B%20d.onclick%20%3D%20d.onmousedown%20%3D%20d.onmouseup%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%20counter%2B%2B%3B%20%7D%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E]
10:36:14.224 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.tagName: html])
10:36:14.232 INFO - Done: [find element: By.tagName: html]
10:36:14.236 INFO - Executing: [mousemove: 6 false])
10:36:14.255 INFO - Done: [mousemove: 6 false]
10:36:14.360 INFO - Executing: [doubleclick: no args])
10:36:14.379 INFO - Done: [doubleclick: no args]
10:36:14.382 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return counter;, []])
10:36:14.396 INFO - Done: [execute script: return counter;, []]
10:36:14.402 INFO - Executing: [get: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Cstyle%3E%23a%7Bwidth%3A8px%3Bheight%3A8px%3B-ms-transform%3Ascale(0.5)%3B-moz-transform%3Ascale(0.5)%3B-webkit-transform%3Ascale(0.5)%3Btransform%3Ascale(0.5)%3B%7D%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22a%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E])
10:36:14.429 INFO - Done: [get: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Cstyle%3E%23a%7Bwidth%3A8px%3Bheight%3A8px%3B-ms-transform%3Ascale(0.5)%3B-moz-transform%3Ascale(0.5)%3B-webkit-transform%3Ascale(0.5)%3Btransform%3Ascale(0.5)%3B%7D%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22a%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E]
10:36:14.434 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return document.getElementById("a");, []])
10:36:14.442 INFO - Done: [execute script: return document.getElementById("a");, []]
10:36:14.446 INFO - Executing: [get element size: 7 [org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@7bae314f -> unknown locator]])
10:36:14.451 INFO - Done: [get element size: 7 [org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@7bae314f -> unknown locator]]
10:36:14.454 INFO - Executing: [get: about:blank])
10:36:14.476 INFO - Done: [get: about:blank]
10:36:14.483 INFO - Executing: [get current url])
10:36:14.484 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return (function getCoverageData() {
        function stringify(value) {
            function escapeString(/*string*/ str) {
                return ('"' + str.replace(/(["\\])/g, '\\$1') + '"')
                    .replace(/[\f]/g, '\\f')
                    .replace(/[\b]/g, '\\b')
                    .replace(/[\n]/g, '\\n')
                    .replace(/[\t]/g, '\\t')
                    .replace(/[\r]/g, '\\r'); // string
            }

            function serialize(value, key) {
.....
10:36:14.837 INFO - Executing: [get: http://localhost:9000/index.html])
```

config

```
define({
    // Default desired capabilities for all environments. Individual capabilities can be overridden by any of the
    // specified browser environments in the `environments` array below as well. See
    // <https://theintern.github.io/intern/#option-capabilities> for links to the different capabilities options for
    // different services.
    //
    // Note that the `build` capability will be filled in with the current commit ID or build tag from the CI
    // environment automatically
    capabilities: {
        'browserstack.selenium_version': '2.45.0'
    },

    // Browsers to run integration testing against. Note that version numbers must be strings if used with Sauce
    // OnDemand. Options that will be permutated are browserName, version, platform, and platformVersion; any other
    // capabilities options specified for an environment will be copied as-is
    environments: [
        //{ browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '11', platform: 'WIN8' },
        //{ browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '10', platform: 'WIN8' },
        //{ browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '9', platform: 'WINDOWS' },
        { browserName: 'firefox', version: '38.2', platform: [ 'LINUX' ] }
        //{ browserName: 'chrome', version: '39', platform: [ 'WINDOWS', 'MAC' ] },
        //{ browserName: 'safari', version: '8', platform: 'MAC' }
    ],


    maxConcurrency: 2,


    tunnel: 'NullTunnel',

    loaderOptions: {
        // Packages that should be registered with the loader in each testing environment
        packages: [ { name: 'myPackage', location: '.' } ]
    },

    // Non-functional test suite(s) to run in each browser
    suites: [ 'tests/aa' ],

    // Functional test suite(s) to execute against each browser once non-functional tests are completed
    functionalSuites: [ 'tests/bb' ],

    // A regular expression matching URLs to files that should not be included in code coverage analysis
    excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:tests|node_modules)\//
});
```

Comment: What version of Intern are you using?

Comment: The "junk requests" are detections for known WebDriver implementation issues.  I've seen this as well when trying to run tests in IE11 with local Selenium (tried both Win8 and a Win7 VM), but can run tests fine against BrowserStack.  On Win8 it seems as if it attempts to handle the data protocol by opening another application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've followed the directions under Required Configuration on the [InternetExplorerDriver wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration).  I ran into an issue like this as well; adding the registry setting mentioned on that page fixed it:

> For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.

As for the "junk requests", they're a standard part of Leadfoot's start-up process.  Leadfoot first runs a battery of tests to detect known WebDriver implementation bugs.